# What is the difference between Emil Artin's Geometric Algebra and David Hestenes Geometric Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

Emil Artin wrote a book on Geometric Algebra. Is this the same as the geometric algebra of David Hestenes?Please correct me if I'm wrong on this, I think David Hestenes geometric algebra is just clifford algebra. Did David change anything from Clifford' original geometric algebra or is he just trying to make it more well known; it seems to be very useful. Anyway, I am just curious if the textbook Geometric Algebra by Artin is also just clifford algebra or geometric algebra? I don't really know the difference between the two. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

No, Artin's *Geometric Algebra* is not about what David Hesetenes is talking about.

Artin's book is a much more general course on the connection between algebra and geometry via groups.  It **does** have a section on Clifford algebras, of which "Hestenes geometric algebras" are a special case.

So far, I've gotten a lot more use out of my copy of Artin's *Geometric Algebra* than out of any of the "Hestenes geometric algebra" material I've read.

I think Hestenes' principal effect has been to raise the profile of using Clifford algebras practically. I don't think I've ever seen anything about truly new results coming out of the program, but indeed since he raised the profile I think people have been taking a closer look at the Hestenes school perspective.

At one of the spectrum, I have seen some things to the effect that phrasing things with geometric algebra can make some things clearer or more memorable.

On the other end of the spectrum, I have seen people say that geometric algebra and the associated geometric calculus is just "for people uncomfortable with basic manifold theory." The whole situation reminds me a little bit of the quaternion/vector-algebra war.

Just remember not to get caught up in hype, because there is a bit of that. Personally, I someday plan to sit down and weigh these things on their virtues, but for now I'm still brushing up my manifold theory :)

Comment: Thank you rschwieb Really?, I didnt know Artin Geometric Algebra was a generalization or Hestenes/Clifford. Do you think Artin's book is still modern and up to date? I would like to study it, but it is dated, and I always worry about reading something with old terminology and symbolism, or old beliefs. Can you recommend a modern book on geometric algebra as taught like Artin. What about his son, Michael Artin who wrote a book on abstract algebra. Will this be in the same spirit as his father's book with a geometric flavour?

Comment: @KayBei There is a little dust on it, but I think for the most part the book still holds up. However, the section on Clifford algebras may not be as clear as other expositions. It constructs the Clifford algebra sort of combinatorically, and it's not as recognizable.  Another book in the same vein is Kaplansky's *Linear algebra: a second course*, which is a little newer. I think both these books could be thought of as similar to Axler's *Linear algebra done right*, but perhaps slightly more advanced and brief.

Comment: @KayBei If you still need an opinion, I've read Artin's Geometric Algebra a while ago. It is definitely a little bit dated, but still feels pretty modern and I've learnt a lot from it.